# How would I get a specific field in this html document using javascript (nodejs)

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, web-scraping

```
<Response>
<SMSMessageData>
    <Message>Sent to 1/1 Total Cost: NGN 2.2000</Message>
    <Recipients>
        <Recipient>
            <number>+9109929199111</number>
            <cost>NGN 2.2000</cost>
            <status>Success</status>
            <statusCode>101</statusCode>
            <messageId>ATXid_f615eb5c6e901459e52d67d045a55355</messageId>
            <messageParts>1</messageParts>
        </Recipient>
    </Recipients>
</SMSMessageData>
```

I want to just extract the element in the number tag using javascript (nodejs) code...............................................................................................

Answer (score 1):

you need to use a parser such as [cheerio](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cheerio)

then you need to read/provide data to it (the HTML), and then you can select the data you need by using its API:

```
const cheerio = require('cheerio');

const data = `
<Response>
<SMSMessageData>
    <Message>Sent to 1/1 Total Cost: NGN 2.2000</Message>
    <Recipients>
        <Recipient>
            <number>+9109929199111</number>
            <cost>NGN 2.2000</cost>
            <status>Success</status>
            <statusCode>101</statusCode>
            <messageId>ATXid_f615eb5c6e901459e52d67d045a55355</messageId>
            <messageParts>1</messageParts>
        </Recipient>
    </Recipients>
</SMSMessageData>
</Response>
`;


const $ = cheerio.load(data);

const num = $('number').text();

console.log(num);
```

Answer (score 0):

Using the `getElementsByTagName` which will return the element with the specified tag (in your case the `number` tag). then you can select the first element use the `innerText` property to extract the text value of the element.

```js
const el = document.getElementsByTagName('number')[0];
console.log(el.innerText);
```

```html
<Response>
<SMSMessageData>
    <Message>Sent to 1/1 Total Cost: NGN 2.2000</Message>
    <Recipients>
        <Recipient>
            <number>+9109929199111</number>
            <cost>NGN 2.2000</cost>
            <status>Success</status>
            <statusCode>101</statusCode>
            <messageId>ATXid_f615eb5c6e901459e52d67d045a55355</messageId>
            <messageParts>1</messageParts>
        </Recipient>
    </Recipients>
</SMSMessageData>
```

Answer (score 0):

To do this, simply tell the system to fetch the  HTML element by calling `document.querySelector("number")`, and then use the `innerText` property to get the text content of the string. Use the code below to set a variable `content` to the text inside of the number tag.

```
var numberElement=document.querySelector("number"); //Fetch the element
var content=numberElement.innerText; //Retrieve its contents
```

Answer (score 0):

You can select a field by it's TagName, however its not a good solution (because you might have some other number fields in future). the better solution is using ID's.
like:

```
const number=document.getElementById('ID').innerText;
```

or:

```
const number=document.querySelector('#ID').innerText;
```